Converting cleveref macros to standard LaTeX
My goal is to create a function in Emacs Lisp to interactively convert macros provided by the cleveref package (\cref, \Cref, etc.) into standard LaTeX:
For example:
\cref{sec:1} --> section~\ref{sec:1}.
To achieve this result, I've considered redefining the macros provided by cleveref in this manner:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldcref}{\cref}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\cref}{ m }{%
  \typeout{\oldcref{#1}}
\oldcref{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section\label{sec:1}}

\cref{sec:1}

\section{Second section\label{sec:2}}
\cref{sec:1,sec:2}

\end{document}

This prints in the log file:
\oldcref {sec:1}
I need it to print:
\cref{sec:1} --> section~\ref{sec:1}
Even more importantly: \cref{sec:1,sec:2} should incorporate
\cref{sec:1,sec:2} --> sections~\ref{sec:1} and \ref{sec:2}
in the .log file.
An output like this might also be suitable (maybe easier to obtain):
\cref{sec:1,sec:2} --> sections 1 and 2
Is it feasible to achieve? Would it be a sufficiently robust solution to be used in a scientific document editing workflow?
I've come to consider a solution like this because in many cases, the poorman option provided by the cleveref package doesn't work (Cleveref's poorman option does't work with hyperref).
Having a list like this in the .log file (or in a dedicated auxiliary file) would allow it to be used for converting macros defined by cleveref into standard LaTeX, and I believe it could be useful to many.
For now, simply expanding the \cref and \Cref macros would be sufficient for me.
(The ultimate goal could be a macro that takes as arguments the macros to be expanded, redefining them appropriately one by one:
\expandCleverefs{\cref,\Cref, etc.}

but, in case, I'll open another question.)
Note. I've tried to provide all the necessary information to "help you help me." Before seeking help, I've attempted to solve the problem using all the resources at my disposal (Google, manuals, AI...), but I have my limitations. I have a lot of respect for the time you'll dedicate to assisting me, and I'll be grateful for it.
Note added. My job involves editing scientific articles prepared by scientists, each of whom uses LaTeX differently. My task is to standardize them to the style of the journals we publish. Pragmatically, I don't need to do everything that the cleveref's poorman option does, but rather redefine \cref and \Cref, which are the main macros of the package. Since I can make the macro conversion interactive, I shouldn't have any problems identifying potential errors. The approach of transitioning from a LaTeX compilation that generates an auxiliary file containing a list of associations between the use of macros in the .tex file and their "effect" in the .pdf is the simplest idea that occurred to me and would be very similar to the approach of the "poorman" option.

@cfr Thank you for the messages. I really appreciate it. My knowledge of LaTeX is limited to the "user" level or slightly above. I thought of using \typeout based on other examples (of which I don't fully understand the workings). In 15 years of copy editing, reviewing around 10,000 papers, I've never come across \cref*... so breaking it (maybe) wouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure I really understand what you mean by patching a LaTeX command, but if I knew which command to patch, I could try.

@cfr (I had tried to look at the cleveref code to understand how the "poorman" option works, but when I start seeing @ in commands, I get lost...)

The code for the "poorman" option goes over 600 lines in the package. That shows that this replacement is in no way trivial and you can't replaced it by some simple patch. It is naturally possible to do what you want but it requires to really analyse the code and implement proper redefinitions. If you can avoid cleveref I would suggest to switch to zref-clever as there you have an active maintainer you can ask for help.

@cfr The theoretical/practical aspect that I'm missing is how to obtain in an auxiliary file what \cref and similar commands generate in the PDF (I refer to the strings and not the hyperlinks). In practice, if \cref{sec:1,sec:2} generates "section 1 and 2" in the PDF, how do I insert this string into the .log file? I have no idea how to do this, and I don't even know if it's possible. What I would like to do is precisely modify a macro to insert into an auxiliary file both the macro call itself and its "effect" in the form of a "string" in the PDF. I hope I've explained myself clearly.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for the comment. My job involves editing scientific articles prepared by scientists, each of whom uses LaTeX differently. My task is to standardize them to the style of the journals we publish. So far, I've never come across the use of the zref-clever package; perhaps it's not yet popular enough. Pragmatically, I don't need to do everything that the poorman option does, but rather redefine \cref and \Cref, which are the main macros of the package. Since I can make the macro conversion interactive, I shouldn't have any problems identifying potential errors.

@UlrikeFischer But I don't think this requires poorman, if I've understood correctly. I think it is meant to provide something much more limited. But I don't know it's possible to figure out the name of the reference type without emulating what cleveref's apparatus does? I'm guessing not.

\cref is  \protect\cref. It's designed  not to expand in the wrong places ....

@cfr Perhaps I've had another idea, but I need to know if the redefinition I've outlined in my question is safe or if it breaks anything. Let me try to explain better; it might be acceptable for me to include the string "\cref{LABELS}" in an auxiliary file without expanding the command (i.e., what it's doing now). Does this redefinition, based on the tests you've conducted, break anything?

@cfr Ok, it breaks \cref*.

It may break other things but, yes, at least \cref*.

@cfr Is there absolutely no way to obtain, in an auxiliary file, at least the macro call string? (You had suggested etoolbox... could it work?)
